# One GridView, two DataSources

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, datasource

So, I have one GridView and 2 DataSources created using "wizard" ( GridViewTasks-->NewDataSource)

I have one CheckBox on my page...when checked=true I want to use DataSource1 for my GridView, and when checked=false DataSource2.

I have tried add CheckBox_CheckedChanged event in my code-behind something like this:

```
    protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox.Checked == true)
    {
        gvPredbiljezbe.DataSource = dsGridView1;
        gvPredbiljezbe.DataBind();
    }

    else
    {
        gvPredbiljezbe.DataSource = dsGridView2;
        gvPredbiljezbe.DataBind();

    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

I know I can go in my code-behind and do it all "manually" (SqlDataConnection->DataAdapter->DataTable->GridViewDataSource) but is there a way when you create your DataSources with GridView wizard and on CheckBox or ButtonClick event change your GridView's DataSource's?

Thanks

Best

K

Comment: could you please specify your problem like what is not working, is it generating some error or the CheckBox changed event is not hitting at all or everything going good but data are not showing at all in gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set AutoPostBack="true" for your checkbox.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

     if (checkbox != null)
         gvPredbiljezbe.DataSourceID = checkbox.Checked ? dsGridView1.ID : dsGridView2.ID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you user1111 this worked like a charm:) Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this technique; don't assign the DatasourceID, then set it in page_init for the initial data load, then do:

```
   protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox.Checked == true)
    {
        gvPredbiljezbe.DataSourceID = dsGridView1.ID;
        gvPredbiljezbe.DataBind();
    }

    else
    {
        gvPredbiljezbe.DataSourceID = dsGridView2.ID;
        gvPredbiljezbe.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Something like that; swapping the ID of the datasource worked without issue (been a little while so I think you use ID, not ClientID property).